# my particle emmiter isnt working

Tags: particles

I am making this smoking pod. My particle emmiter is placed underneath the balls inside the pod but no smoke comes out. A whole load of smoke came out for a second or so I have no idea why it did or why it isn't now. Also when the smoke did come out it went right through the pod and the balls whereas if possible I would like it to drify up around the balls and out like it is a smoking caldron. i also want the smoke to be white

[image: smokin pod]

Comment: Looks like your normals are all flipped

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the balls as a group (ctrl+G). With the balls selected, go to physics tab, click "collisions" and select your group under the SMOKE tab.

2nd: Your smoke sim dies too early. I can see you have 250 frames active in your timeline. So you click on your smoke domain and click on -behaviour- uncheck dissolve.

Now, to really make it efficient:
create a shere (ctrl+a). With the ball selected:
Press space bar. Type on the search : Quick smoke. 
Press ALT+A. (it will play your smoke for the 250 frames simulating a cache).
Press ESC. (to stop your sim)
Select the balls you want to act as a collider.
Make them group.Name them "colliderballs"
With the group still selected: Go to physics tab. Press: SMOKE and select "collision" button.
Thattá do it.